# Storm's fault tolerance: is the data lost when a worker died

Tags: apache-storm, fault-tolerance

I got a question about the fault tolerance. Considering the word count=
 ing topology you have given, the bolt "WordCount" may have many tasks, and "fieldsGrouping" is used to ensure the same word always be assigned to the same task. 
My question is, what if some tasks died? For my understanding, storm will try to restart these tasks. But when restarting, the word counts stored in these tasks should lost as well. Does it mean that these words will start from 0 in other or restored tasks?

Answer (score 0):

Yes. The internal state that is stored in `Map<String, Integer> counts = new HashMap<String, Integer>();` is lost on failure and after restart the counts for all words assigned to the failed tasks will be zero after restart.

If you want to backup the state, you need to do this either manually in your code using a reliable distributed backend storage system (such that you can restore the state after recovery---of course also manually in your own code), or you use Trident API that provides some primitives for stateful processing: https://storm.apache.org/documentation/Trident-state.html

Comment: I thought I can also store all the data in the database rather than in memory. Instead of updating a HashMap, I can just update the database directly. For my understanding, this is also what trident does, is that correct?

Comment: Yes. That is what I meant by "reliable storage".